# C++ Operator Overloading in Class with Const Members?

Tags: c++, constants, overloading, operator-keyword

```
class SomeClass {
    int someNum;
    const int someConst;
    public:
        SomeClass() : someNum(12), someConst(15)
        {
        }
        SomeClass operator+(int num) {
            SomeClass newSomeClass;
            newSomeClass.someNum += num;
            return newSomeClass;
        }
};

int main() {
    SomeClass someClass;
    SomeClass newClass;
    newClass = someClass + 3;
}
```

I don't understand why the above doesn't compile, but does so when the const related code is removed.

Comment: Maybe look up what `const` means?

Comment: How do you expect `newClass = someClass + 3;` to work?

Comment: If there is a function which prints out someNum, I expect the value of it to be 15 in newClass.

To juanchopanza's point, is it because newClass is being assigned a new someConst with a different memory address albeit the same value? If so, how would I use operator overloading in a class with consts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [const members and operator=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721865/const-members-and-operator)

Comment: "... why the above doesn't compile.." - when it fails to compile, the error message emitted, which you inconveniently omitted from your post, surely attempts to expand some reason for *why* ? Pro Tip: If you *ever* have questions about an *error*, your question should *include the error messaging verbatim*, and your assessment of what you think it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
SomeClass newClass;
newClass = someClass + 3;
```

With the first instruction you create the object *newClass* and the member variable is initialized:

```
[...] someNum(12), someConst(15) [...]
```

With the second instruction you're trying to assign a new object constructed by the *operator+* to the object.

So actually you're trying to *modify* the object itself which has a *const* variable member.

C++ provides a default *assignment operator*:

```
newClass = someClass + 3;
```

means *"copy all variable mambers in the object on the right side of the = in the object in the left side"*.

In that case the variable *someConst* is declared as constant value, so you cannot overwrite its value. Indeed the operation make a compile error.

### Solution

In order to handle this "problem" you need to write a *custom assignment operator*.

That's an example:

```
class SomeClass {
int someNum;
const int someConst;
public:
    SomeClass() : someNum(12), someConst(15)
    {
    }
    SomeClass operator+(int num) {
        SomeClass newSomeClass;
        newSomeClass.someNum += num;
        return newSomeClass;
    }

   // Custom assignment operator
   SomeClass& operator=(const SomeClass& oth) {
     if (this != &oth) {
       this->someNum = oth.someNum;
     }
     return *this;
   }
};
```

In that way you're telling to copy from an object just the member variable *someNum* and to avoid the cost member.